# How to display images inside the new tab in Python

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tabs, pyqt

Suppose that I have 10 images in a directory, and need them to be displayed inside a newly created tab once the user presses a push-button. The images must be displayed according to a 5x5 grid with a proper image label.

I have designed a GUI using Qt Designer containing three different tabs (tab1, tab2 and tab3), but it seems like this will not work for me - the images wouldn't display inside tab3. How can I make it done by using command-line coding rather than using Qt Designer in order to display all the images?

Below is the function to display the images:

```
# Display image at 'Tab 3' once user press button 'Display'
def display_result(self):

    # Get wafer qty
    qty = int(self.qty_selected)
    print('qty -> ' + str(qty))

    # Get lot id
    name = str(self.lotId)
    print ('lotId -> ' + str(name))

    for index in range(int(qty)):   
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
        path = r'c:\Users\mohd_faizal4\Desktop\Python\Testing\%s\%s_%d.jpeg' % (name, name, index + 1)
        print('load (%s) %r' % (pixmap.load(path), path))
        item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(os.path.basename(path))
        item.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(path))
        self.viewer.addItem(item)


    contents = QtGui.QWidget(self.tabWidget)
    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(contents)
    self.tabWidget.addTab(contents, 'Tab 4')
```

I would like to display all the images inside 'Tab 4', instead of opening a another window.

[image: tab 3]

Comment: I suggest using some qt tags if you're using qt and asking about qt...

Comment: Already update tags to include pyqt

Comment: This is too open ended. Show the code you have tried, and indicate where in this code you are not getting expected result.

Comment: i have update the question and elaborate the problem. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I'd like to help but your question is unclear. You mention you are unable to show image in tab 3 but then you talk about tab 4. Remember that we know nothing about your application. Keep it simple: only put here what is essential to the problem. For example, it appears tabs 1 and 2 are not relevant to the issue. Copy your app code, then remove everything that is not essential but still reproduces the problem. Then post that code, including the ui file so that we can copy it into our IDE and run it.

Comment: @Schollii - sorry for that,i should improve it in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new list-widget for each tab. Here's a demo:

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.tabs = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)
        self.edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('New Tab', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.createNewTab)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.tabs, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.button, 1, 1)

    def createNewTab(self):
        viewer = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        viewer.setViewMode(QtGui.QListView.IconMode)
        viewer.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(256, 256))
        viewer.setResizeMode(QtGui.QListView.Adjust)
        viewer.setSpacing(10)
        name = self.edit.text()
        for index in range(5):
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
            path = r'c:\Users\mohd_faizal4\Desktop\Python\Testing\%s\%s_%d.jpeg' % (name, name, index + 1)
            print('load (%s) %r' % (pixmap.load(path), path))
            item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(os.path.basename(path))
            item.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(path))
            viewer.addItem(item)
        index = self.tabs.count()
        self.tabs.addTab(viewer, 'Tab%d' % (index + 1))
        self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(index)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(800, 150, 650, 500)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easly display an image inside the tab by creating a label in the tab, here is an example for that : ( the tab in my example is tab_3)

`def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 30, 241, 171))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label_181.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("images/A_01.png"))
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")`

so here you will get the image inside the tab.I hope that will help you.

Comment: How about if I need to display a multiple image in the label inside tab by grid view 5x5? I'm really new in Python programming.

Comment: You create multiple label inside the tab and then you set geometry of each label in order to avoid interference and in each label you load a picture inside it.